# How to automatically access strings.xml? (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, string, intellij-idea

I have a bunch of strings in strings.xml,
all the id's/names of the strings have a pattern (e0,e1,e2,e3,e4...)
I would like to display one of the 23 strings I have depending on
what number the user chooses. For example, if the user chooses
the number 6, than I would want to display the string "e6".
How can I do that without using a super long switch statement?

I'm using IntelliJ Idea

Thank's for the Help, All your answers worked and were useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a String Array

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

EXAMPLE:

XML file saved at res/values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves a string array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Michael's example, I would do something like this:

```
Int num; //the number the user chooses

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewID);

tv.setText(planets[num - 1]); //arrays start at zero so you would have to subtract one to get the right string. And also so you dont reference a nonexistent variable in the array.
```

Comment: Thank's for reminding me to subtract 1 from 'num', otherwise I would forget myself